# window.open goes to null url when used with a variable (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code to get the link to bookmarking a topic on a phpBB forum

```
var bookmark = document.getElementsByClassName('bookmark-link');
console.log(bookmark)
var bookmark_array = Array.from(bookmark);
console.log(bookmark_array)
bookmark_array.length = 1;
console.log(bookmark_array)
var str = bookmark_array.toString();
console.log(str)
var link = str.match('\/viewtopic\.php\?f=(\d+)&t=(\d+)&bookmark=1&hash=(\w+)');
console.log(link)
window.open(link);
setTimeout(() => {  window.close(link); }, 3000);
```

(console logs are just to visualize what's going on)

But window.open goes to a url like `https://my.site.com/null` in the end

The console log for `link` however shows the correct link I want to go to

When I execute it manually (copying the url from console.log(link) output, then doing `window.open("what I copied"`) it works just fine

I assumed it's the issue with quotes, but enclosing `link` in them will result in `https://my.site.com/"null"`

I have popups enabled in Chrome for that site and it's whitelisted in all my adblockers.

So I'm really in the dark as to the reason why this happens

Thank you!

Comment: `str.match()` returns an array, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar 
How should I go about fixing it? .toString returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null`. I want to keep the code structure as is, since it's my first day coding in JS, so even though it's not very good at least I understand how it works

Comment: If you're getting null, it means it didn't match the regexp.

Comment: That's why the URL is `null`.

Comment: There are many strange things in your code. Why do you set the array length to 1? If you just want the first element, use `bookmark_array[0]`.

Comment: If you want the URL that it links to, use `bookmark_array[0].href`.

Comment: But console.log(link) shows the exact link I need, so it must've matched somehow. As for the other things, I want to solve this first and then make small adjustments if necessary.

Comment: I believe it has more than 1 href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has lots of unnecessary complexity. I've simplified it below.

The reason you're going to `null` is because the bookmark doesn't match the pattern you're testing with `str.match()`, so it returns `null`. You need to check for that.

```
var bookmark = document.getElementsByClassName('bookmark-link');
console.log(bookmark)
var first_bookmark = bookmark[0];
var url = first_bookmark.href;
console.log(url)
var link = url.match(/\/viewtopic\.php\?f=(\d+)&t=(\d+)&bookmark=1&hash=(\w+)/);
if (link) {
    window.open(url);
    setTimeout(() => {  window.close(link); }, 3000);
} else {
    alert("Bookmark link doesn't match the pattern");
}
```